# mysql - join table row based on id with the highest column value in the table - multiple joins and conditions

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

**I have searched on SO prior to asking and have tried things I found - I have more involved due to multiple joins and conditions and cannot get the correct results.**

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5fc13/1) with basic data entered.

The query below does not give the results I want, but gives an idea of what I am looking to achieve. I want to return 1 result per computer_id where time.capture_timestamp is between a specific start/end value and is the highest value in the table for that computer_id including that row's other column values. I have tried a few different things I found here on SO involving MAX() and subqueries, but can't seem to get what I am looking for.

```
SELECT
  computers.computer_name,
  users.username,
  time.title,
  time.capture_timestamp
FROM computers
INNER JOIN time
  ON time.computer_id = computers.computer_id AND time.capture_timestamp >= 0 AND time.capture_timestamp <= 9999999999
INNER JOIN users
  ON users.user_id = time.user_id
GROUP BY computers.computer_id
ORDER BY time.capture_timestamp DESC
```

The fiddle as is will return :

```
computer_name   username    title           capture_timestamp
computer1       user1       some title      1595524341
computer2       user3       some title3     1595524331
```

while the result I would like is actually :

```
computer_name   username    title           capture_timestamp
computer1       user2       some title2     1595524351
computer2       user3       some title3     1595524331
```

... based on the example values in the fiddle. Yes, the start/end time values include 'everything' in this example, but in use there would actually be a timestamp range provided.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.computer_name, u.username, t.title, t.capture_timestamp,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.computer_id
                              ORDER BY t.capture_timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM computers c
    INNER JOIN time t ON t.computer_id = c.computer_id
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = t.user_id
    WHERE t.capture_timestamp BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999
)

SELECT computer_name, username, title, capture_timestamp
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Would have never thought of this without seeing it first.  If I am understanding this correctly it is just sorting `capture_timestamp` in a temporary partition then later only selecting the first row in that partition?  Ordering ASC would give the min found.  Any particular reason for using this way other than say the other answer shown here?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but the version I gave above is probably the best way of doing this assuming you are on MySQL 8+.  If you are on earlier versions, then use the answer by @MKhalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a correlated sub query to get the desired results

```
select
  computers.computer_name,
  users.username,
  t.title,
  t.capture_timestamp
from computers
inner join time t
  on t.computer_id = computers.computer_id 
  and t.capture_timestamp >= 0 and t.capture_timestamp <= 9999999999
inner join users
  on users.user_id = t.user_id
where t.capture_timestamp =(
  select max(capture_timestamp)
  from time
  where capture_timestamp >= 0 and capture_timestamp <= 9999999999
  and t.computer_id = computer_id
)
order by t.capture_timestamp desc
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5fc13/3)

Comment: Thank you.  This looks pretty much identical to what I was trying based off other posts here on SO, but could not the expected results.  This does get the correct results though.